# Mapping STFT magnitude to sound intensity level

Tags: frequency-spectrum, stft, psychoacoustics

I have a signal for which I have computed my STFT magnitude spectrum in dB. The plot is the following:
[image: STFT]

This is my magnitude spectrum in dB computed with `matplotlib specgram` function. As far as I know, this plot returns values for `20*log10(fft_value)`.

I also know that the sound intensity is computed as showed [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sound_intensity).

I am trying to perform a JND intensity analysis between two signals (following the schemes showed [here](http://cyrille.pinton.free.fr/electroac/lectures_utiles/son/Olson.pdf) at page 575 of the book, not the PDF).

I do not know if it is a reasonable approach. I wanted to compute the error between two signals, my reference and my computed output, then compute the STFT of this error. Finally, if for each frequency bin in my spectrum, the dB intensity value of the error signal is lower than 1/3 dB (following the plots in the above mentioned book), then basically the error is not audible.

What I am missing is a "mapping" between the magnitude spectrum in dB and the sound intensity in dB. Is it possible to achieve what I asked? Is it a reasonable approach? If yes, how?

Comment: The sound intensity is a time integral of multiplication of sound pressure and particle velocity. So if you can't obtain sound intensity if you don't have both p and v, unless the wave front is known such as plane wave. If you just want to calculate $10\log_{10}|p(f)|^2$ which is equal to the SPL $20\log_{10}p$, the unit of FFT results is the same as the original time domain signal.

Comment: I followed a similar approach as you suggested in the end. I have my error signal as mentioned in my question. I am using the JND curves as "comparison" to decide whether or not the difference between my output signal and the reference signal will be heard. I will describe my approach in a following comment due to limitation on the length

Comment: I am using an headphones system, reading the literature i decided that the maximum SPL allowed by my system is 80dB SPL (limit for hearing damage). My error signal has a maximum STFT value of -90dB FS. In air, I assumed that SPL and Sound Intensity Level are equivalent (from here: https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/9113/how-sound-intensity-db-and-sound-pressure-level-db-are-related). I can use the SPL levels even if JND curves use sound intensity level. 80dB - 95dB = -15dB -> The sound is basically inaudible with such SPL values

Comment: Given the above result, it suggests that the error is so small that it is basically inaudible to the final listener, considering also the JND curves. Is it a reasonable approach? Obviously it is evaluated also with psychoacustical tests, which confirm my original idea (the error is inaudible)